# How do I submit all fields within a php while tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to post the generated form to a second file for further processing, however only the last entry is sent to the second file. How do I send all information in the loop to the second page? Additionally the `$_POST['STAMP']` entry is not being posted. Do I need a different approach to retrieve the DB data?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="payc.php" method="post">
Pay Range 
  <input type="date" name="start">
<input type="date" name="stop">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "Pass";
$dbname = "DB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TIME WHERE STAMP BETWEEN '". $_POST['start']."' AND '".$_POST['stop']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo "<form action=\"test.php\" method=\"post\">";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$duration=(($row['T_OUT']-$row['T_IN'])/60)/60;


        echo "<fieldset><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date\" value=\"".$_POST['STAMP']."\"><input name=\"EMP\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['EMP']. "\"><input name=\"time\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $duration. "\"><input name=\"ITEM\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $row['ITEM']. "\"><input name=\"NOTE\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $row['NOTE']. "\"></fieldset>";

        }
echo "<input type=\"submit\">";
echo "</form>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
foreach($_POST as $results){
var_dump($results);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: All the "rows" overwrite each other in your attempt. You have to use something like that: `<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date[]\" value=\"".'somevalue'."\">` (note the `[]` in the name attribute...) That way you create an array with all values as elements in the receiving side.

Comment: How do I fix the problem?

Comment: @arkascha Im not understanding. Could you elaborate for me? :)

Comment: If you post several input fields with exactly the same name, then in the receiving script all those post arguments will just overwrite each other. Instead you add the `[]` behind the name, that way the receiving script will construct an array with the name and put each value of each hidden input field as element into that array. Then you can access the values: `$_POST['date'][0]`, `$_POST['date'][1]` ... `$_POST['date'][n]`

Comment: @arkascha Its only outputting array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: @arkascha how do I group all the `$_POST` together?

Comment: That means you did not construct your hidden input fields correctly. I suggest you add your current code to the question. We cannot help without you providing precise and current information about your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all the fields have the same name at every loop

The solution consists of two parts:

```
<input name="date[]">
<input name="EMP[]">
<input name="time[]">
<input name="ITEM[]">
<input name="NOTE[]">
```

Which will identify it as array not one input

Second part at the test.php file
Instead of getting one input with $_POST['date']
It will return an array so you have to loop over them

```
$info = array();
for ( $index = 0 ; $index < count($_POST['date']) ; $index++ )
{
    $record = array();
    $record['date'] = $_POST['date'][$index];
    $record['EMP'] = $_POST['EMP'][$index];
    $record['time'] = $_POST['time'][$index];
    $record['ITEM'] = $_POST['ITEM'][$index];
    $record['NOTE'] = $_POST['NOTE'][$index];
    $info[] = $record
}
```

Comment: Its only outputting `array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: There are 4 submissions. So thats correct, but its missing all other info.

Comment: yes you have to loop over all of them it is just sample
i will update the answer to work with all of them

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I combine them into a single array?

Comment: I need each `<fieldset>` to be its own array.

Comment: Any time, yes ok i edited the answer
now $record will contains one fieldset array which you want,
and $info will contains all the fieldsets

Answer (score -2):

1) You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

2) You never check if the form was submitted at all - your php code runs regardless of HOW the page was loaded. At minimum, you should have something like

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
   ... db stuf ...
}
```

Comment: And how is that meant to be an answer to the question? That should have been comments maybe.

Comment: `the $_POST['STAMP'] entry is not being posted`